# Porque este em javascript/html/css está lento para Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Já pesquisei muito, já mexi no código mas nada ajuda... alguém sabe me dizer porque este jogo roda travando nos mobiles, e algum jeito de otimiza-lo??

código completo: https://github.com/Dinicley/ElephantGame
demo: http://elephantgame.dinicleyalves.com.br/

Comment: Use a aba "Performance" da Dev Tools (ctrl+f12) do Chrome para avaliar o desempenho da aplicação.

Comment: obrigado, consegui me localizar com isso vlwww.